# Can't send files through bluetooth on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade

I just upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1

While I was using Windows 8, everything seemed to work fine. When I upgraded to Windows 8.1, I realized that I cannot send files through bluetooth.

I still have the bluetooth icon on my Notification Area but upon trying to search for activated bluetooths in range, I cannot find any. Also, upon checking the Task Manager, my bluetooth is "not connected" but it was enabled and updated in the Device Manager.

When choosing the Devices part of the Settings, all I can see are my wireless network and my usb mouse. I tried to search for other "devices" but it returns to my computer with the label "Digital Media Player".

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Search `fsquirt` at the Start Screen, and then if you want to send a file just choose 'send files', if you want to receive files, just choose 'Receive Files'

Comment: I mean, no, it doesn't work. When sending files it displays 'This folder is empty' and it doesn't have anything like choose folders or what. how to work this out?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your Bluetooth devices in range, with Bluetooth enabled on them, and either:

1. Are they configured to be visible to other Bluetooth devices?
2. Is the device you want to send files to paired with the computer?

When you click "Send files", the next screen (with the title "Select where to send your files") should show a list of Bluetooth devices either in range or paired with the computer. Only when you select one of the devices will it present you with the next screen allowing you to select which files to send.

If you cannot see any Bluetooth devices in range of the computer and they definitely are configured to be visible, perhaps the upgrade to Windows 8.1 broke your Bluetooth device drivers. Look up the latest drivers on the manufacturer website and try reinstalling them.